# Spring + Angular: How to parse ResponseEntity in angular?

Tags: spring, angular, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot to create an API that needs to be consumed in Angular 4. Spring and Angular are on different ports.

**The problem is that Spring's ResponseEntity raises an error in Angular.**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity getFlow(@PathVariable int id) {
        Flow flow = flowService.findById(id);

        return new ResponseEntity(flow, HttpStatus.FOUND);
    }
```

Now, I can perfectly use Postman to test the API and it works.
[image]

But when I make a request from Angular, it returns an error:
[image]

[image]

Strangely, it returns an error alongside the requested object.

Now, the cause of the problem is that the Spring Boot application returns a ResponseEntity and not a normal object (like String), and Angular doesn't know how to interpret it. If the controller returns just a Flow object, it works.

How can it be solved using ResponseEntity? Or, how else can I send the object alongside the HTTP status code?

Comment: is there any specific reason why HttpStatus.Found is used ? it is a successful response try sending HttpStatus.Ok

Answer (score 1):

Also, in @RequestMapping put produces = "application/json", and in get request in angular, add http options :

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
};
```

So your get request looks like this:

```
this.http.get(url, httpOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the document mentioned here

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

> A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success status and will result in the success callback being called. Any response status code outside of that range is considered an error status and will result in the error callback being called. Also, status codes less than -1 are normalized to zero. -1 usually means the request was aborted, e.g. using a config.timeout. Note that if the response is a redirect, XMLHttpRequest will transparently follow it, meaning that the outcome (success or error) will be determined by the final response status code.

As you are sending an instance of ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.Found) whose Http status code is 302 which doesnt fall under the success range thats why error callback is called.

Comment: i have used HttpStatus.OK which is 200. still i am struck with same issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try returning the content like this

```
return new ResponseEntity(flow, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Comment: Code-only answers should be avoided since they may only resolve the issue, but the people with this problem should understand minimally why this code resolves the question. Could you please explain what this code does and why it resolves the original question?